# Swift 3 Migration: Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, apple-watch

arrayOfDicts is declared as

```
let accelManager = CMSensorRecorder()
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var arrayOfDicts:[NSDictionary] = []
```

The function is defined as

```
    func startMotionManager() {
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.start)
    self.arrayOfDicts = []
    if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
        let handler:CMAccelerometerHandler = {(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            self.arrayOfDicts.append([
                "timestamp":data!.timestamp,
                "x":data!.acceleration.x,
                "y":data!.acceleration.y,
                "z":data!.acceleration.z
                ])
            //print("timestamp: ", data!.timestamp, ", x: ", data!.acceleration.x, ", y: ", data!.acceleration.y, ", z: ", data!.acceleration.z)
        }
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue(), withHandler: handler)
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the "let handler" line.

"Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred
   In call to function 'append'"

I have done some poking around and think it is because the complier isn't sure what type array "arrayOfDicts" is...but I could be way off. Any help and/or education on the subject will be greatly appreciated.

-Matt

Comment: Why are you using Dictionaries if they always have the same 4 keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure type `CMAccelerometerHandler` has been changed to:

```
public typealias CMAccelerometerHandler = (CMAccelerometerData?, Error?) -> Swift.Void
```

(From the generated header of "CMMotionManager.h".)

Try changing the `NSError?` in that line to `Error?`.

You may sometimes need to take such error messages like "cannot be inferred" as "there may be some type related errors". Send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to promote Apple (or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/)) to improve such diagnostics.